# How to pass data to two bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Hi i am performing crud operations on a table. So i have to perform two operations like reset password and to delete the entry. I have added a bootstrap modal to confirm the action. I am able to pass the value and use the first modal but when i click on second modal it does not fire up.

My code is as follow:-

```
<td>
    <a href='#' data-href='modules/reset.php?id={$row['id']}' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#resetpassword' data-popup='tooltip' title='Reset Password'><i class='icon-lock2'></i></a>

    <a href='#' data-href='modules/delete.php?id={$row['id']}' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modal_delete' data-popup='tooltip' title='Delete'><i class='icon-trash'></i></a></li>
</td>
```

Modals:-

Delete password modal:

```
<div id="modal_delete" class="modal fade" style="font-weight: normal;">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header"></div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                        <i class="fa fa-warning fa-5x"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div>  

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                                <br/><h5>Are you sure you want to delete?</h5><br/>
                            </div>
                            <div>   

                                <div class="modal-footer text-center">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-ok">Yes, delete it!</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Reset password modal:

```
<div id="resetpassword" class="modal fade" style="font-weight: normal;">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header"></div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                        <i class="fa fa-warning fa-5x"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div>  

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                                <br/><h5>Are you sure you want to reset password?</h5><br/>
                            </div>
                            <div>   

                                <div class="modal-footer text-center">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-oks">Yes, reset it!</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Javascript:-

```
<script>
    $('#modal_delete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
        $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
    });
</script>

<script>
    $('#resetpassword').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
        $(this).find('.btn-oks').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
    });
</script>
```

By this method only the delete modal works but the reset modal does not fire up. The modal whose javascript function is before only works. How to make both of them work. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should enclose your script inside jquery on  ready                      $( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should enclose your script inside jquery on ready

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 //your javascript code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of your `<div>`s should be `</div>`. If you look carefully you will see that the reset password modal is actually within the delete password modal code.

**EDIT:** Slightly off topic, and I understand if you would prefer to roll your own, but have you tried [SweetAlert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/)? They have some nice looking alert boxes and it's pretty easy to use.